# Querying MongoDB with geoSearch fails with error "can't find ns"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I am experimenting with MongoDB for storing simple geospatial point data (ordinarily I would use PostGIS).  I am using MongoDB v2.6 which I am accessing through Node.js and Mongoose (v3.8.22).

I have a test schema as follows (based on the patterns in [mongoose-geojson-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-geojson-schema) as there seems to be little consistency in advice on the cannonical geojson schema set up in MongoDB even in the documentation):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var placesSchema = new Schema({
    'geom': {
        'type' : { type: String, default: "Point" },
        'coordinates': [{type: "Number"}]
    },
    'pointType': String,
    'placeName': String,
    'comment': String
});
placesSchema.index({'coordinates' : 'geoHaystack', 'pointType' : 1},{bucketSize : 1});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Places', placesSchema);
```

I populate the collection with dummy data:

```
{ pointType: 'Place', name: 'Little Snoring', comment: 'Bogus, Dude!', geom: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-20.0, 5.0] }},
{ pointType: 'Place', name: 'Fantasia Hollow', comment: 'Awesome!', geom: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [6.0, 10.0] }},
{ pointType: 'Place', name: "Lion's Den", comment: 'Growl-tastic', geom: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [34.0, -50.0] }},
{ pointType: 'Place', name: 'Dun Roamin', comment: 'So unoriginal', geom: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-100.0, 70.0] }},
{ pointType: 'Sausage', name: 'Floodsville', comment: 'No way (sad face)', geom: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [38.0, 38.0] }}
```

...and look at it via the Mongo client shell, which shows that the DB is created correctly and has an index.  The index quotes the namespace value as "ns: geojsonExample.places" (which is what I expect).

In my main file I call:

```
var places = require('../lib/places');  //import my schema
places.geoSearch({ 'pointType' : 'Place' }, { near : [-20.0, 5.0], maxDistance : 50 }, function (err, results, stats) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Result: ' + results);
});
```

The geoSearch call throws this message: `MongoError: can't find ns`

```
E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:246
        throw message;
              ^
MongoError: can't find ns
    at Object.toError (E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\utils.js:114:11)
    at E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1173:31
    at E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1882:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:453:41)
    at E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:487:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\responses\mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:445:20)
    at emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (E:\MONGOOSE_GEOJSON\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:201:1
3)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
```

I'm at a loss of how to solve this because I can see the ns value correctly stored in the index.  Is my geoSearch request wrong or is there some Mongoose 'gotcha' I need to know about?  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me when I test it. Verify that `places` is what you expect it to be. You use geohaystack indices with points on a flat place `[x, y]` and not GeoJSON. Are you sure you don't want a 2dsphere index?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  I traced the problem to the asynchronous data-loading and indexing in the node environment.  So if I wrap the dummy data load in async.each, the problem goes away.  Apparently you can use geoHaystack with geoJSON (which doesn't need to be in spherical coordinates).  However, 2dsphere will actually give me greater flexibility.